# Python and BeautifulSoup4 - How to Debug Post Request Responses?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am attempting to login to Amazon vendor central via requests and beautifulsoup modules.

My code runs fine until, I attempt to print the landing page content in order to verify that I have logged in.

When I print the page, the contents of the login page appears.
Is anyone able to identify where I am going wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://vendorcentral.amazon.co.uk/'
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get(site)
html = resp.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')

data = {}
form = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signIn'})
for field in form.find_all('input'):
    try:
        data[field['name']] = field['value']
    except:
        pass

data['email'] = 'name@email.com'
data['password'] = 'Password123'

post_resp = session.post('https://vendorcentral.amazon.co.uk/', data = data)


 post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_resp.content , 'lxml')
    if post_soup.find_all (id='a-page'):
        print('Login Successfull')
    else:
        print('Login Failed')

print(post_soup.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon sends a lot of data params in the form not only email and password.

Simple example in Chrome: `Chrome -> devtools -> network -> XHR` `copy as curl` copy and convert to the requests lib here(https://curl.trillworks.com/).

- you need to check headers too.

Comment: Since the link in the answer above doesn't work anymore, here is alternative link to curl converter: https://curlconverter.com/python/